# global data space in RTI's implementation of DDS

Tags: udp, publish-subscribe, data-distribution-service, opendds

Can anyone explain briefly about the global data space in DDS?
Is it like a virtual memory?? When does a global data space is required?? 
I know that in Unicast of UDPv4, for every dataWriter/dataReader pair one port is assigned through which the communications take place between dataWriter and dataReader ,then from where does the concept of global data space come ?

Answer (score 0):

The global dataspace is an abstract concept.  It is not a physical existence.

UDP and shmem are simply transports.

Where the shared dataspace might be embodied (shared memory, malloc'd memory, in buffers spread out across drivers, wherever) is a function of the implementation details, and something you can start out by ignoring, while keeping in mind that the *concept* is something you can use to understand where the data is maintained while it is motion.

As the system integrator, or system implementer, you only need to understand that the DDS implementation provides, to your applications, a global dataspace for the data to exist in as necessary.

The DDS implementation takes your published data and pushes it to the global dataspace.  The DDS implementation takes data out of the global dataspace and hands it to your applications, based on its announced subscriptions.

How the DDS implementation chooses to present the global, shared dataspace to your application will depend on the implementation details, and will be discussed in the higher-level documentation.  *How* it implements the "dataspace" will be in the lower-level documentation which you may never need to refer to.

rw

Comment: Will global data space behave like a cache for a data writer where he stores the data  and when a subscriber joins lately in the communication,he will get this old samples from this cache?Is it like this?Can you explain briefly??

Comment: Read the spec. In short: yes, you are asking about DW persistence, there are four levels between not at all and fully persistent but fully persistent requires additional tools (an application that subscribes and stores data in an RDBMS for example, and makes the data available to late joiners).

Comment: Can you please provide me the link to the spec??

Comment: Search terms:  OMG-DDS specification download.  The OMG does not charge money for its specifications.  It is free to download.